# Why using blocks swallow exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement

I recently ran into a problem with exception handling in using statement. The problem is that exceptions which throws inside 'using block' could swallowed, for example look at code:

```
class DisposableObject : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new Exception("dispose");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var obj = new DisposableObject())
            {
                throw new Exception("using");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example you will see 'dispose' in output, first exception will be ignored and you will never know about it. After some searching i found article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056(v=vs.110).aspx about common mistakes about use using block. But my question isn't about how to avoid exception swallowing, i' want to know why MS decided to unwrap using block to

```
try
{
...
}
finally
{
}
```

and not the otherwise, for example they could unwrap using to something like this:

```
//this code prevents exception swallowing
try
{                       
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        if (obj != null)
            obj.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception disposeEx)
    {
        throw new AggregateException(ex, disposeEx);
    }

    throw;
}
if(obj != null)
    obj.Dispose();
```

Comment: This is a smart question. They could have done this to prevent errors from being lost. await has a similar problem. It throws away all but one error (often not deterministic which one).

Comment: @usr It seems questionable to create a new exception with a different type that doesn't appear in the code. Early on, C# had a "no surprises" design, although certainly this has been relaxed now.

Comment: @mikez Alternative, they could have put first exception into some property on second exception.

Answer (score 4):

Because `AggregateException` didn't exist when the `using()` block was created.

Also because `Dispose()` is really not supposed to throw.

Finally, because there are subtle semantic differences between your example and a `finally` block, with regard to exception filters, stack unwinding, and critical regions.

Comment: They could have created AggregateException.

Comment: I don't think that absence of AggregateException is a problem, it's very simple class. Also if Dispose is really not supposed to throw but in fact Dispose can throw exceptions in many popular libraries, for example WCF(client proxy can throw exception on disposing). Third, I just have wrote sample code, that demonstrate how to avoid swallowing, and it can be written with finally block(i think but i can wrong).